# Why I am getting 401 on OAuth and ADAL.JS with AD FS 2016

Tags: oauth, adfs, adal, adal.js

I am following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/single-page-application-with-ad-fs and I am cloning the code from github and following all the steps to create Application Group in ADFS and modifying the changes in the code. It works fine and clicking on SignIn or trying to visit the Todo list page took me to the ADFS login page and then it redirects me back to the application page but when I try the "Todo List" page it gave me the `{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}`. 
Checked the Network traffic in chrome developer tools (and also in Fiddler) and the request to TodoList (Request URL: https://localhost:44326/api/TodoList) has the Authorization header:
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Inp4anhjL
Looking at all the other traffic everything else is fine.

The https://pdc.mkdomain.com:44326/#/UserData shows the following results:

```
Id_token content
mohsen@mkdomain.com
aud:https://pdc.mkdomain.com:44326/
iss:https://PDC.mkdomain.com/adfs
iat:1551610099
nbf:
exp:1551613699
ver:
tid:
amr:
oid:
upn:mohsen@mkdomain.com
unique_name:Mohsen@mkdomain.com
sub:JIg5DslCMEyKf8AnKpvNg3XQf+KN58tgOzYEjlZ+WZA=
family_name:
given_name:
pwd_exp:
pwd_url:
```

In relaying party trust I have:

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => issue(store = "Active Directory", 
types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", 
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress", 
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname", 
"family_name"), 
query = ";displayName,mail,givenName,sn;{0}", param = c.Value);
```

and in Insuance transform rules I have:

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", 
Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => issue(store = "Active Directory", 
types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress", 
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname", 
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname", 
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group", 
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname"), 
query = ";mail,givenName,sn,tokenGroups(SID),sAMAccountName;{0}", 
param = c.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was the ida:Issuer value was lowercase while the machine name was upper case. As soon as I changed it from pdc.MKDOMAIN.com/adfs to PDC.MKDOMAIN.com/adfs everything worked.